# StackOverflow when initializing new object

Tags: java, stack-overflow

I have no idea why is this happenning, it seems to be in a constant loop between creating new object and initializing it

```
public class App {

Character hero = new Character();
charCreation charCreation = new charCreation();

public static void main(String [] args){
    App app = new App();
    app.run();
}
    void run(){
        charCreation.charCreate();
         
    }
    



}
```

So here App creates a new charCreation object which is this

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class charCreation extends App {

Scanner skan = new Scanner(System.in);

protected  void charCreate(){
    
......
```

And here's the error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
>
> at charCreation.(charCreation.java:3)
>
> at App.(App.java:5)
>
> at charCreation.(charCreation.java:3)
>
> at App.(App.java:5)
>
> ......

it goes on and on

Comment: How can we see which code throws error? Please post your charCreation class codes

Comment: The error is thrown at

"class charCreation extends App {"

Comment: Your `charCreation` is an `App` which contains a `charCreation` which is an `App` etc, etc.

Comment: What comes first? Chicken or Egg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create an instance of `CharCreation` (fixed CamelCase for you), it will also initialize everything inherited from its superclass `App` (calling the superclass constructor, initializing all the instance fields, etc). Part of that is creating another instance of `CharCreation` (as well as an instance of `Character`).

Infinite loop.

Maybe you want to remove that instance field from `App` and make it a local variable in `run` instead.

Answer (score 2):

The `charCreation` class extends `App` so to create it it needs to call the constructor of the superclass (`App`). To construct the `App` superclass, the fields of `App` need to be costructed, including a `new charCreation()` - and so it loops.

You need to decouple creation of a new `charCreation` object from the creation of the `App` instance.

Answer (score 1):

You have an `App` class with a field of type `CharCreation`.

`CharCreation` extends `App`, so when you initialize a `CharCreation` object, it will initialize the field `charCreation`. And so, when the `charCreation` field is initialized, it will initialize a new `CharCreation` object, and so on.

It's basically a design issue you have to solve, and I think you `CharCreation` class shouldn't extends the `App` class, and `charCreate` should return a `Character`.

```
public class App {
    Character hero = new Character();
    CharCreation charCreation = new charCreation();

    void run(){
        hero = charCreation.charCreate();

    }
}

public class CharCreation {
   public Character charCreate() {
       /* creates and returns the hero */
   }
}
```

Side note:

- Always name your classes with a first upper letter to match the java convention, `CharCreation` and not `charCreation`.
- Don't use `Character` to name a class, it's a class which already exist in the JDK (the object counterpart of `char`).

Answer (score 0):

Cyclic object creation which caused stackoverflow.

1. App object create charCreation instance object
2. charCreation object will also create App Object as it is super class.[super class object instantiate before child]
3. Cycle found, go on... till the stackoverflow.